# Cannot Write To php://temp with segmentation fault

Tags: php

I am getting there error message of:

```
Warning: Unable to create temporary file in /libraries/Guzzle6/GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 370
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The segmentation fault does seem to have an out. When I look into line 370 of CurlFactory, it is:

```
$conf[CURLOPT_FILE] = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
```

I have set my /tmp directory to 777. What else could be causing this error?

Comment: I don't have a sure answer, but just some immediate thoughts that come to mind: perhaps it could be an issue of disk space or memory to allocate space for the filehandle?

Comment: The file is 8GB, I have 40 GB available.

Comment: What does `echo sys_get_temp_dir();` output? Is that folder chmoded to 777 and/or does your httpd process have access to write to this directory?